# Gradle executes different set of unit tests in different environments

Tags: java, unit-testing, jenkins, gradle

I have a (rather big) project with multiple suprojects, all build with Gradle. I've noticed that Gradle runs a different set of unit tests when run locally (on dev laptop), and different on the official Jenkins build server:

```
> cat test.log.local.txt | grep "<long regexp>" | wc -l
2781
> cat test.log.jenkins.txt | grep "<long regexp>" | wc -l
2795
```

It is not a surprise, that tests that run on Jenkins, fail.

Does anyone has a clue why Gradle selects a different set of tests on different machines?

Comment: Do you have any dedicated settings for tests in `build.gradle`?

Comment: Only this: `test { jvmArgs "-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m" }`.

Comment: Compare the gradle command run in the dev laptop versus the gradle command run in Jenkins, are they the same? Check version of gradle is same on both dev boxes and Jenkins box (run `gradle -v`) Then review your wc command, review the line differences, what are they? Gradle is reliable, widely used and well tested it is unlikely to be the root cause of your problem but you will need to provide more information on the build before anyone can help you here.

Comment: Yeah, I did all of those already. The Gradle version is the same (specified in build.gradle), the command is exactly the same (`./gradlew build --info`), the difference shows the names of the tests that are run in one environment, but not the other. I also tried running Gradle with --debug, but it didn't give me any hints. Version of Java is the same. I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Then there must be something in the build that checks the environment sees its not a dev env and runs different tests, or the same test suite runs but produces different results, without providing more detail it will be tough for anyone here to point out the problem.

Comment: On one hand, I have a unique problem nobody seems to ever seen before. Exciting! On the other hand – I still have a problem I struggle to solve. :D